# Is it possible to create proto-personas just with quantitative research?

Tags: user-research, ux-designer, personas

I have been asked by one of my client that use our current surveys and google analytics and create Proto-Personas for our Website. The website is quite complex.

They don't want to spend any money right now on any workshops. They think their stakeholders time is valuable and I can pull together proto-personas and later on full personas with their research.

Do you think it's feasible to do either of those tasks (creating Proto-personas and personas)?

**Note:**They have never done any user interviews.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes of course, that's why they are proto-personas. As a matter of fact, if you have some user data, protopersonas will be way more accurate.

[A proto-persona has four quadrants](http://www.dtelepathy.com/blog/philosophy/how-to-make-proto-pesonas):

- Biography & Picture
- Demographics
- Needs & Goals
- Behaviors.

Proto-personas are completely subjective and based on your team's idea of who your users would be.

It's easy to see that if you have some surveys or Google Analytics, you can add some pizazz to these proto-personas and infer REAL demographics, REAL behaviors and even REAL needs and goals. Of course, this will depend on the analytics you have, but having some data will always be more accurate than having no data at all.

However, the concept of proto-personas creation requires that not only you creates them, but you'll need different views from different people in your team. And I understand that your stakeholder's time might be valuable, but time restrictions is not an excuse. It may take like 10 minutes to create a proto-persona and these 10 minutes will be highly compensated by the obtained results

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In my case client doesn't see the value of Proto-Persona and Persona workshop and asking for examples in advance.